# how to repeat same pdf form (fillable) again and again

Tags: pdf

i need to fill same one page form 20 times for different persons. now when i made 20 copies of that form and merged them.(i need all them as in one file and in fillable formate not in static by printing them). so i merged them but now if i enter a name in first form it automatically get copied in rest of all 19 pages with same field. 
if i change name in any other form like if in page 9 it will auto update reset of all pages. it means i am not able to put different names in that file having same type of fillable pages with same field.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the fields of each PDF file before merging them, otherwise every reference to a field named "LastName" will be treated as the same field, even if the references are on different pages. You could add some kind of unique prefix, for example you can have a counter for your files and put it as prefix of each field.